# Adding a Class to a link_to Helper With Only 1 Parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <% if user.profile %>
        <%= link_to user do %>
            <h2><%= user.profile.first_name %> <%= user.profile.last_name %></h2>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The above code works fine. What this code does is that it will output the first and last names of every user. These names are clickable and will take me to that user's page. My main issue is with the 3rd line. The issue I am having is that I am trying to get rid of the link underline, but I am unsure as to how to pass a class into it. Below is my attempt. My class "no-text-dec" is just one line of "text-decoration: none;"

```
<%= link_to (user, class: "no-text-dec") do %>
```

I'm new to Rails, but I understand that link_to has a body, url options, and then html options in that specific order, but how can I make it work in this case? The above line makes my application is crash, but it's the only thing I can think of that makes sense. I'm assuming it's because I am not giving it its body argument, but I'm not sure what that would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine if user contains url/path correct

```
<%= link_to(user, class: 'some_class') %>  do
  <span>Delete</span>
<% end %>
```

The space after method in sending argument in helper method link_to is crashing your application

you can give a try at irb

```
def test(a,b)
 puts a; puts b;
end

test ("Ad","Cd")
```

It should throw an error

Comment: I always make the silliest mistakes and then make myself look dumb on Stack. Thank you and thank goodness for anonymity! lol Also, FYI I think you forgot to close your link_to with a %>, but it's all good.

Comment: Yes, i forget to close with `%>` :)